# Anne Sacoolas extradition refusal - pending judicial review?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, diplomatic-immunity

Anne Sacoolas is accused of killing Harry Dunn in a road accident in the UK and then fleeing the country to the USA to avoid prosecution under cover of diplomatic immunity. (Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Harry_Dunn)

It was reported in https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-northamptonshire-52630089 that...

> .."The White House may feel that secretary Pompeo's refusal to extradite
> Anne Sacoolas was final but that does not reflect the real position.
>
> "In fact quite the contrary, as the US Embassy in London said in a
> recent letter to Andrea Leadsom, both countries recognise that the
> final decision will rest with the court following a judicial review."

What "judicial review" is this referring to?

Answer (score 2):

The letter from the US Embassy to Andrea Leadsom referred to by the family's lawyer appears to be the one detailed in this [BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-northamptonshire-52546897), which doesn't appear to have been published in full.

> In a letter addressed to Ms Leadsom, Yael Lempert, deputy chief of
> mission at the US Embassy in London, said: "Regrettably, at this time
> we are unable to meet with the Dunn family directly or discuss
> specifics of the case surrounding their son's tragic death.
>
> "The family's spokesperson has publicly announced the family's
> intention to make an imminent filing of a lawsuit against the United
> States Government.
>
> "Given the strong interest of both countries to ensure proper judicial
> review, we have been advised that it would not be appropriate to
> engage in a discussion which might touch on that matter."

The judicial review referred to, therefore, appears to relate to the [announced intention](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/oct/29/family-of-harry-dunn-announce-plan-to-sue-trump-administration) of Harry Dunn's family to sue the Trump administration:

> The Dunn family’s lawyer, Radd Seiger, who left for the US on Sunday,
> made the announcement about the fresh legal action after instructing
> lawyers in the US.
>
> “We are bringing claims against both Mrs Sacoolas in the US for civil
> damages as well as the Trump administration for their lawless
> misconduct and attempt to cover that up,” he said in a statement.
>
> “No one is above the law and the family are determined to ensure that
> this never happens to another family again. It will be Harry’s
> memorial. His legacy.”
>
> Seiger claimed the US government had tried to “twist and contort the
> laws on diplomatic immunity”.
>
> He added: “The Trump administration is not only hellbent on breaking
> international laws, rules and conventions on diplomatic immunity, but
> they have no care or concern for the welfare of Harry’s family or any
> real intent on finding a solution.”

However, these plans to sue the US government were recently (31st Aug) [dropped](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2020/aug/31/harry-dunns-family-drop-plans-to-sue-us-government), in order to 'find a "resolution to the impasse"'.

> The 19-year-old’s parents, Charlotte Charles and Tim Dunn, previously
> said they would pursue a claim against Donald Trump’s administration
> for its handling of their son’s case.
>
> But Charles has told the Press Association that the family “can now
> see that the US government are working towards” suspect Anne Sacoolas
> facing the UK justice system.
>
> The US Department of State recently said it was looking for a
> “reasonable resolution” after news emerged that the UK attorney
> general, Suella Braverman, was considering the possibility of a
> virtual trial or a trial in Sacoolas’s absence.
>
> The Dunn family said they hoped their decision to no longer pursue a
> claim against the US government would encourage them to meet with the
> family and discuss a way forward in their quest for a trial in the UK.

There have been a few other judicial reviews floated, a review into the advice given by the Foreign & Commonwealth Office to Northamptonshire Police, and a review of the Foreign Secretary's actions, for example. However, the action referred to in the article in the question refers to Dunn's parents' intention to sue the US government, which has now been dropped.